# How to filter category wise products and display it on same all products page without creating extra category.html

Tags: django, web, view, backend

I actuallu stuck on this problem that where i have an index.html page, it shows all stores and their category and if someone clicks on this category i want to filter out stores by that category and i want to show this stores on same index.html page without creating extra category.html so here my code

```
View.py
def index(request,stores_name=None):
  stores = stores_model.objects.all()
  context = {'stores': stores}
  return render(request,'Stores/index.html', context)





def categories(request , cats):
  categoriesproduct = stores_model.objects.filter(scategory = cats)
  context = {'categoriesproduct':categoriesproduct}
  return render(request , 'Stores/categories.html')



index.html

{%for i in stores%}
   {{i.stores_name}}
   <a href={{i.get_absolute_url}}>{{i.category}}</a>

{%endfor%}
```

is any idea if someone click on category then same index.html should open and instead of all stores only stores of that category should show

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET parameters:

```
stores = stores_model.objects.all()
category = request.GET.get('category', None)

if category:
    stores = stores.filter(category=category)
```

Then in you url you must pass the get parameters like so:
`yoursite.com?category=somecategory`

Comment: I don't understand about url can you explained in brief?

Comment: I mean how can pass get parameters like can you give me some example ?